# C# list vs byte array efficiency over network

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine, networking

Okay so I'm trying to make a multiplayer game using a self built netcode in unity3d using c#,

The thing is since I'm using raw tcp I need to convert everything to a byte[] but I got sick of using Array.Copy. Since I'm reserving a few bytes of every message sent over a network as sort of a message identifier that I can use to interpret the data I receive.

So my question is, for the purpose of making this code more friendly to myself, is it a terrible idea to use a list of bytes instead of a byte array and once I've prepared the message to be sent I can just call .ToArray on that list?

Would this be terrible for performance?

Comment: the efficiency over the network doesnt depend on the implementation in your code; if you're worried about network efficiency or speed you might want to think about udp

Comment: I wasn't talking about the efficiency of the network here. I was more so worried about wether using a list instead of using the array.copy function would be a concern for local performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule when dealing with sockets: you should usually be working with *oversized* arrays (`ArrayPool<byte>.Shared` can be useful here), and then use the `Send` overloads that accepts either the `byte[], int, int` (offset+count), or `ArraySegment<byte>` - so you aren't constantly re-copying things, and can re-use buffers. However, frankly: you may also way to look into ["pipelines"](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html); this is the new IO API that Kestrel uses that deals with all the buffer management *for you*, so you don't have to. In the core framework, pipelines is currently mostly server-focused, but this is being improved hopefully in .NET 5 as part of "Bedrock" - however, client-side pipelines wrappers are available in `Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial` (on NuGet).

To be explicit: no, constantly calling `ToArray()` on a `List<byte>` is *not* a good way of making buffers more convenient; that *will probably work*, but could contribute to GC stalls, plus it is unnecessary overhead in your socket code.

Comment: Alright I'll look into some of the stuff you suggested. Thank you for your advice.